# Installing Lubuntu with ended support for old laptop

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I have a more than 10 year old HP laptop. It came with Windows XP, which today is obsolete.

I want to install Lubuntu on it (because it's old), but it does not support boot from pen-drive, and the only option I detect is using a CD. I have a 650 MB one but that is insufficient space for the latest version of Lubuntu.

I found older versions which would fit in that CD, however they are not supported anymore. My main concern is safety against malware and such threats.

Should I install that older version (that fits the CD) or are there other feasible ways of installing the latest LTS release?

Specs of the laptop (HP Pavilion ze2000):

- CPU: AMD Semprom 3000+ (1.8 GHz)
- Graphics: ATI RADEON XPRESS 200M
- RAM: 1.12 GB

Comment: Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD and you'll find a number of images that are smaller than 100mb.  Are you sure you don't have a DVD drive? I run lubuntu 16.04 LTS on a 2005 thinkpad t43 (and it came with cd/dvd combo).  My t43 cpu won't use the x86_64 version and the i386 iso isn't available in 18.04, but you can still upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 once installed (if necessary). If you install the minimal install; you can then add what you want (be it `lubuntu-desktop` or other..)

Comment: Please tell us more about the more than 10 year old HP laptop: Brand name and model of the laptop, of the CPU and of the graphics chip/card, How much RAM is there? It will help us help you.

Comment: Now that I know more about the hardware I suggest that you try a current version of the Ubuntu `mini.iso` according to the instructions by @guiverc. See also this link, [Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD and you'll find a number of images that are smaller than 100mb.

*Are you sure you don't have a DVD drive? I run lubuntu 16.04 LTS on a 2005 thinkpad t43 (and it came with cd/dvd combo). My t43 cpu can't boot the x86_64 version and the i386 iso isn't available in 18.04, but you can still upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 once installed (if necessary).  My t43 installed, and I run Lubuntu 16.04 LTS happily (with the option to upgrade to 18.04 should I sometime wish to)*

If you install the minimal install; you can then add what you want (be it lubuntu-desktop or other..)

I would definitely go this route (or another to use a supported version), over using an unsupported, unpatched OS unless it's never going to be connected to the internet, nor share files with other machines (via LAN) etc. *Better safe than sorry, because you forgot for a second..*

Comment: fyi: Paul.  My t43 also has XFCE & MATE DEsktops installed (*added after Lubuntu installation*).   If I was to `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04 I'd know my option to run MATE would be gone (it has moved to all GTK+3 which could be too slow in my 1.5GB of ram and single-core cpu), and as more of XFCE would also be using GTK+3 [in 18.04] it'd likely be slower too.  I've stuck with 16.04 LTS as it's still supported until 2021.April :)

Comment: +1 for recommending to start from the Ubuntu `mini.iso`. @PaulAliban, The new version 18.04 LTS works for me with old hardware - I can get Lubuntu installed and working well. A week ago I even tested with the developing version Cosmic (to become 18.10), and it worked too (from the corresponding Cosmic `mini.iso` file.